# How come this python typings check doesn't understand I'm returning a bool?

Tags: python, python-typing

I have two methods, both type annotated in python3.

The first being:

```py
def is_user_edit_only(self) -> bool:
    company = self.get_company()
    if company:
        return company.is_company_edit_only()
    return False
```

and the `method is_company_edit_only` looks like this:

```py
def is_company_edit_only(self) -> bool:
    return bool(*internal company logic)
```

the actual logic isnt important, the functions work just fine.  My question is, how come I get the type error `error: Returning Any from function declared to return "bool"` why cant mypy tell that the method being called in `is_user_edit_only` returning a bool since it is also labelled as returning a bool? Why does it think its returning any???

Comment: What version of Python and mypy are you using? I can't reproduce that error given your example code. Can you update your question to include a complete reproducer (that is, something we can copy and paste into a file to reproduce the error using `mypy`)?

Comment: Is the `get_company` method annotated to return an instance of the correct class with the `is_company_edit_only` method? Mypy might not know what type `company` has

Answer (score 2):

This is probably a problem with `company = self.get_company()`. You need to include a hint that this is of type `Company`. For example:

```py
class Company:
    ...
    def is_company_edit_only(self) -> bool:
        return bool(*internal company logic)
```

and when using this class

```py
def is_user_edit_only(self) -> bool:
    company: Company  # <- include this type hint
    company = self.get_company()
    if company:
        return company.is_company_edit_only()
    return False
```

This way, it is clear that `company.is_company_edit_only()` will return a `bool`.

Comment: cant import Company here because of a circular import, however this does sound plausible.